# ImportError: No module named urls, Creando vista en django

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando crear una vista en Django y al hacer el runserver me da el siguiente error:

```
> Performing system checks...
> 
> Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at
> 0x0000000004523278> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py",
> line 226, in wrapper
>     fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
> line 121, in inner_run
>     self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 374, in check
>     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 361, in _run_checks
>     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\registry.py",
> line 81, in run_checks
>     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 14, in check_url_config
>     return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 24, in check_resolver
>     for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py",
> line 35, in __get__
>     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 313, in url_patterns
>     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py",
> line 35, in __get__
>     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 306, in urlconf_module
>     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>     __import__(name)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\probardjango\src\pdj\urls.py", line 21, in
> <module>
>     url(r'', 'boletin.views.incio', name='inicio'),   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\conf\urls\__init__.py",
> line 85, in url
>     raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().') TypeError: view must be a callable or a
> list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Archivo 'views.py':

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def inicio(request):
return render(request, "inicio.html", {})
```

Archivo 'urls.py':

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', 'boletin.views.incio', name='inicio'),
]
```

Archivo 'settings.py':

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'boletin',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'pdj.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Estructura:
[image: estructura]

Espero que me podáis ayudar, gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: Dice que no encuentra `boletin.urls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal, ya veo

verás, django 1.10 que es el que estás utilizando no permite hacer esto.

```
 url(r'', 'boletin.views.incio', name='inicio'),
```

en versiones anteriores era la forma de hacer los imports de las urls, ahora la forma correcta sería:

si deseas hacer el import directo en el urls.py de tu proyecto debaría quedar así:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from boletin.views import inicio

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', inicio, name='inicio'),
]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente era por eso. Un saludo

Comment: No hay de que, Saludos

Comment: @manuxdjent Si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, debes marcarla como aceptada. A la izquierda de la respuesta, debajo de la votación esta la marca.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer te falta crear el archivo **urls.py** dentro de tu aplicación de boletín.

Según veo, en la linea 22 del **urls.py** de tu proyecto, estás haciendo un:

```
url(r'', include('boletin.urls'))
```

Lo cual lleva a *Django* a buscar ese archivo que no existe.

Comment: Si, lo siento puesto otra salida que me daba el 'runserver' probando con el include, acabo de editar la pregunta y he puesto lo que me da.